# Directions From a Binary Tree Node to Another: Memory Limit Exceeded

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree, shortest-path

I was solving LeetCode problem [2096. Step-By-Step Directions From a Binary Tree Node to Another](https://leetcode.com/problems/step-by-step-directions-from-a-binary-tree-node-to-another/):

> You are given the `root` of a **binary tree** with `n` nodes. Each node is uniquely assigned a value from `1` to `n`. You are also given an integer `startValue` representing the value of the start node `s`, and a different integer `destValue` representing the value of the destination node `t`.
>
> Find the **shortest path** starting from node `s` and ending at node `t`. Generate step-by-step directions of such path as a string consisting of only the **uppercase** letters `'L'`, `'R'`, and `'U'`. Each letter indicates a specific direction:
>
> - `'L'` means to go from a node to its **left child** node.
> - `'R'` means to go from a node to its **right child** node.
> - `'U'` means to go from a node to its **parent** node.
>
> *Return the step-by-step directions of the **shortest path** from node `s` to node `t`.*

This is the code I submitted:

```
class Solution {
public:
    map<TreeNode*,TreeNode*>parent;
    TreeNode* start = NULL;
    string global ="";
    
    void trav(TreeNode* root , int startValue )
    {
        
       if(root==NULL)
         {
               return ;
         }
        if(root->val==startValue )
        {
          start = root;  
        }
        if(root->left)
        {
            parent[root->left] = root ;
            trav( root->left, startValue);
        }
        if(root->right)
        {
            parent[root->right] = root ;
            trav( root->right, startValue);
        }        
    }
    
    void  direct(TreeNode* root, int destValue, TreeNode *prev , string path )
    {
        
        if(root==NULL )
        {
            return;
        }
        if(root->val == destValue)
        {
            global += path;
            return ;
        }
        if(root->left!=prev)
        {
              direct(root->left,destValue, root,path+"L");
        }
      
           if(root->right!=prev)
        {
              direct(root->right,destValue, root,path+"R");
        }
        
         direct(parent[root],destValue,root, path+"U");
   }
    
    
    string getDirections(TreeNode* root, int startValue, int destValue)
    { 
       parent[root]= NULL; 
       trav(root, startValue);
       direct(start,destValue, NULL,"");
       parent.clear();
       return global ;
    }
    
    
};
```

When I ran it on a compiler ([Link](https://codeshare.io/wnEkm9)) it ran with no error. But submitting the code on the platform ([Submission Link](https://leetcode.com/submissions/detail/784230116/) ) gives a memory limit error.

I know I have created a map globally, but that should not be the cause of this error as the error occurs even when running a single test case.

I am stuck on this issue. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one issue here.

- `direct` may get into an infinite recursion problem, because the last recursive call is made without first checking if that would lead to the previously visited node. You did this correctly for going to the left or the right child, but when going to the parent, you didn't do this check. It should be:

  ```
  if (parent[root] != prev) 
  {
      direct(parent[root],destValue,root, path+"U");
  }
  ```

  With this bugfix the code will pass many more test cases, as long as enough memory is available.
- But, even if you fix the previous bug, the memory usage will still be too much. There are testcases with trees of 100K nodes, and which are skewed, so that each node has at the most one child, giving it a height that is also near 100K. By consequence the recursion depth can also become 100K. And at each recursive call a new string (`path`) is created that gets longer and longer... meaning the combined space needed for those path strings is O(n²) and combined with the stack space we get a space complexity of O(n³) in that case. For `n` equal to 100K this becomes too big for the memory available on the testing platform.

This second issue can be solved by taking the following actions -- staying as close as possible to your original code:

- Don't use the `path` parameter, so to avoid creating that many strings.
- Make the function return a boolean to indicate that the destination has been found. When a recursive call returns true, the caller should not have to continue the search with an other recursive call.
- Only start building the path once the destination is found, adding a direction to the path while returning from the recursive calls -- so in reverse order. Your `global` variable can be used to collect this path. This way only one string is built, not many, and it is extended character by character with the `+=` assignment operator.
- In the main program, reverse this string before returning it.

Here is your code with those changes:

```
    bool direct(TreeNode* root, int destValue, TreeNode *prev) // No path parameter, return boolean
    {
        if(root==NULL )
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(root->val == destValue)
        {
            global = ""; // Start building a path from the end
            return true; // Indicate that destination was found
        }
        if(root->left!=prev)
        {
            if (direct(root->left,destValue, root)) { // Use the returned boolean
                global += "L"; // Append in which direction we found the destination
                return true; // ... and indicate success
            }
        }
      
        if(root->right!=prev)
        {
            if (direct(root->right,destValue, root)) {
                global += "R";
                return true;
            }
        }
        
        if(parent[root]!=prev) // Don't go back up when we just had come down
        {
            if (direct(parent[root],destValue, root)) {
                global += "U";
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false; // Didn't find the destination in this subtree
   }
    
    
    string getDirections(TreeNode* root, int startValue, int destValue)
    { 
        parent[root]= NULL;
        trav(root, startValue);
        direct(start,destValue, NULL);
        reverse(begin(global), end(global)); // Reverse the path
        parent.clear();
        return global;
    }
```

#### More efficiency

There are algorithms where you don't need to have this `parent` map. They only need one traversal of the tree and will therefore do the job faster in most cases.

Hint: Imagine you know the two downward paths from the root to *both* nodes, how could you use that information to return the result?

Comment: WOW !!! Thanks, that was a really impressive in-depth explanation. For the downward path, I will find the LCA of both the nodes and try to generate the paths ...